# UI is not Creating Shapes

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, arraylist

I have a simple example that is supposed to create a set of green balls, but instead is only creating one. I want to create an ArrayList to hold the balls, but something is wrong. Please Help.

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.security.auth.x500.X500Principal;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyBall extends JPanel{

    Random rand = new Random();
    int xr = rand.nextInt(400);
    int yr = rand.nextInt(400);
    int size = 10 ;
    int x = xr ;
    int y = yr ;

    Ellipse2D.Double ball = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 30, 30);
    ArrayList<Bubbles> balls = new ArrayList<Bubbles>();
    Bubbles blobsOb = new Bubbles(x, y , size , Color.GREEN);


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 =(Graphics2D)g;


        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2.fill(ball);
        g2.setColor(Color.green);

        for (int j = 0 ;  j < 10 ; j++)]{
          for(int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++){
              balls.add(blobsOb);
              g.setColor(Color.green);
              g.fillOval(x, y, size, size);

          }         
      }
  }

}

//SECOND CLASS 
import javax.swing.*;

public  class Main   {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyBall p = new MyBall();
        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        f.add(p);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setLocation(200,200);
        f.setSize(400, 420);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

}


//Third Class

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;

// this class is for the properties of green balls 
public class Bubbles extends Component {
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int size;
    public Color color;
    public static Bubbles blob = new Bubbles(250,250,100,Color.BLUE);

    Bubbles(int x, int y, int size, Color c){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.size = size;
        this.color = c;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillOval(x, y, size, size);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your exact issue? The question is pretty broad.

Comment: @coinbird I don't know how to create array list to hold balls are created continuously

Comment: You just make it a list, then you don't have to initialize with a size. List<MyBall> list = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: so what should I do ?

Comment: Use your new List. Now every iteration through your loop you can add your new ball to the List. There is no size limit, you can add as many as you want. Or do what the guy below said, and make a new instance every cycle. Either way will work.

Comment: Don't update the state from within the `paintComponent` method, painting should paint the current state and nothing else. Instead you should have some kind of "main" loop which creates new instances of your entities and updates their states before scheduling repaints

Answer (score 2):

You need to create new instance in every cycle

```
for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++)
    {  
         // ...
         balls.add(new Bubbles(xr, yr , size , Color.GREEN));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to create array list which holds green balls but the problem
>   is I just get one green ball instead of (10) or more

First, this should be inside the loop:

```
Bubbles blobsOb = new Bubbles(x, y , size , Color.GREEN);
```

then you'll also need to insert the code below inside the loop to ensure that at each iteration there is a new generated random value.

```
int xr = rand.nextInt(400);
int yr = rand.nextInt(400);
int size = 10;
int x = xr ;
int y = yr ;
```

example:

```
for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++)
    {  
         int xr = rand.nextInt(400);
         int yr = rand.nextInt(400);
         int size = 10;
         Bubbles blobsOb = new Bubbles(xr, yr , size , Color.GREEN);
         balls.add(blobsOb);
         g.setColor(Color.green);
         g.fillOval(x, y, size, size);

    }

}
```

you should always call `.setVisible(true)` after all the components have been added to the `frame`.

```
MyBall p = new MyBall();
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.add(p);      
f.setLocation(200,200);
f.setSize(400, 420);
f.setVisible(true);
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Lastly but not least, you've added all the generated `Bubble` objects into the ArrayList  `ArrayList<Bubbles> balls = new ArrayList<Bubbles>()`, However, you haven't used the `balls` ArrayList yet.

Comment: you are just amazing .... ok do you know how can I call each time one ball ?for example every 3 seconds a ball come up and thank you so much

Comment: Mohammed you've added all the bubble objects into the ArrayList **balls** however you didn't use the ArrayList yet.